# vb.net from string to listbox line by line

Tags: html, vb.net, string, listbox, html-agility-pack

i made an `webrequest`to get an htmlcode of an website and then i extract the 
the wanted links with `htmlagilitypack`
like this :

```
    'webrequest'
    Dim rt As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim wRequest As WebRequest
    Dim WResponse As WebResponse
    Dim SR As StreamReader
    wRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create(rt)
    WResponse = wRequest.GetResponse
    SR = New StreamReader(WResponse.GetResponseStream)
    rt = SR.ReadToEnd
    TextBox2.Text = rt

    'htmlagility to extract the links'
    Dim htmlDoc1 As New HtmlDocument()
    htmlDoc1.LoadHtml(rt)
    Dim links = htmlDoc1.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='catlist-listview']/ul/li/a")
    Dim hrefs = links.Cast(Of HtmlNode).Select(Function(x) x.GetAttributeValue("href", ""))
    'join the `hrefs`, separated by newline, into one string'
    textbox3.text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, hrefs)
```

the links are like this :

```
http://wantedlink1 
http://wantedlink2 
http://wantedlink3 
http://wantedlink4
http://wantedlink5
http://wantedlink6
http://wantedlink7
```

Now i want to add every line in the string to listbox instead of textbox
**one item for each line**

**THERE IS ABOUT 400** `http://wantedlink`

Comment: is this information in a textbox in this format?

Comment: And what have you tried?  Binding a collection to a list box is generally pretty straightforward...

Comment: @CharlesMay  yes it is in this format in textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hrefs` in your case already contained `IEnumerable(Of String)`. Joining them into one string and then split it again to make it work is weird. Since `String.Split()` returns array, maybe you only need to project `hrefs` into array to make `.AddRange()` to work :

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(hrefs.ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the AddRange method of the listbox's items collection and pass it the lines array of the textbox.

[AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true)

[Lines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.Lines%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true)

Hint: It's one line of code.

Comment: i want to delete the textbox i already try 
`listbox1.items.addrange(textbox3.lines)` and it work but i want to  Get rid of textbox

Comment: remove the entire textbox i want only listbox

Comment: remove it from the controls collection of it's parent container. `me.Controls.Remove(YourTextBox)` Then after that I like to do a `YourTextBox = Nothing`  me in this case being the Form. You may have to dot in to other containers depending on where your textbox resides.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you didn't just fill the listbox in the beginning instead of getting another control involved that you get rid of later.

Comment: i know how to remove it 
look here is the details i mad a  `webrequest` to get html code and then i used `htmlagilitypack` to extract these  links `http://wantedlink`  from the `htmldocument` 
and now i want to put every link in listbox one by one

Comment: If this Answer did not resolve what you're trying to do then go back and edit your question based on what you've changed it to over the course of this topic. You originally asked how to add the contents of a multiline textbox to a listbox and then later you stated you knew how to do that but you wanted to remove the textbox. Now with this last comment you're using a term `one by one` so I'm confused if this has been any help at all with your requirements now.

Comment: i m sorry for the poor details in the  question i edit it now i hope you help me in this Thank You

Answer (score 0):

its ok i find the answer

```
  Dim linklist = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, hrefs)
  Dim parts As String() = linklist.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine},
                                   StringSplitOptions.None)
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(parts)
```

this add all the 400 links to the listbox